# Java BigInteger with very large binary numbers

Tags: java, binary, biginteger, randomaccessfile

i have 2 very large binary numbers (144 digits). I want to write them in different RandomAccessFiles and then read the files to memory and check to see which number is bigger.
What i did so far:

1.
I created a BigInteger:

```
BigInteger big = new BigInteger("01110101010010101010111100010101010101010101010110101010101010101010010101010101010101010101010101111010010101010",2);
```

2.
I get the longValue:

```
big.longValue();
```

3.. I write the long to a randomaccessfile,read the files,compare the longs etc...

But if the binary is longer than the **'Long.maxvalue'** what i did is wrong, correct?

So does anyone have any suggestions?

Can i handle large binary numbers otherwise?

Comment: Why dont you just write the big integer to file? BigIntegers are serializable by default. Check on ObjectInputStream. You can also check on simply writing the string equivalent to file.

Comment: You could use a [bit stream](http://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/cps100e/spring11/assign/huff/code/BitInputStream.html). Theoretically a long should not be used to represent bits.

Answer (score 1):

try comparing as below

```
           BigInteger big1 = new BigInteger("01110101010010101010111100010101010101010101010110101010101010101010010101010101010101010101010101111010010101010",2);
           BigInteger big2 = new BigInteger("01110101010010101010111100010101010101010101010110101010101010101010010101010101010101010101010101111010010101010",2);
           int result =big1.compareTo(big2);
           System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Since i am using RandomAccessFile i would like to be able to seek. I don't know much about serialization, can i write my BigInteger serialized as String?I want to know how many bytes it will need on the file so as to seek when i read the files. That's why i convert it to long (8 bytes).I want to a file: write int,write int,write large binary,write int,write int,write large binary....etc and then be able to read all the values and compare the binary numbers.

Answer (score 0):

1. eliminate initial zeros
2. Convert these numbers to Strings
3. if(String1.length !=String.length ) maximum number is the longer one

else

take one by one digit from the beginning and compare.

if(string1 digit x = 0 & string 2 digit x=0) go to next digit

if(string1 digit x = 1 & string 2 digit x=0) String 1 is big

if(string1 digit x = 0 & string 2 digit x=1) String 2 is big

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, your number is too large for a long.

I recommend you to export your BigInteger as a byte array using `BigInteger.getByteArray()`, and then you can save it to a file (that's what we do in cryptography).

Also, the byte array can be converted back to a BigInteger using its contructor.

Comment: So vincent and upong thanks a lot. What i should do is convert the binary number to BigInteger, write it to file using getByteArray(), read it from file using constructor BigInteger(byteArray[]) and then compare the BigIntegers using big1.compareTo(big2). I sum up for anyone else having same problem. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to mark this answer as the solution if you see fit.